# FPDF not merge some PDF files - FPDF_merge.php

Tags: php, merge, fpdf

They are 190 invoices generated by FPDF as PDF-file. if i am trying to merge with FPDF_merge.php it gives me at 27.invoice fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: reference d'object inconnue in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\fpdf\fpdf_merge.php:74 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\web\fpdf\fpdf_merge.php(181): FPDF_Merge->error('reference d'obj...') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\web\fpdf\fpdf_merge.php(666): FPDF_Merge->getObject(Resource id #32, Array, NULL, true) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\web\pages\merge-rechnungen.php(43): FPDF_Merge->add('../data/customer...') 
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\fpdf\fpdf_merge.php on line 74*
```

**I use the same code to merge delivery notes there it works fine.**  I see this error cames by 4 invoices but all invoices were generated in same way with FPDF. Have somebody any idea THX...

Comment: Check whether the problematic pdf files are encrypted

Comment: Try using [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/) instead.